# MapReduce FIFO scheduler

Tags: mapreduce

I have a question about MapReduce FIFO scheduler. I understand jobs are executed as they arrive in the queue (as long as they have the same priority). My understanding is that the next job will wait until current job is done. But what if current job is not completely consuming the capacity and the next job can be running with the remaining capacity? In that case, the next job will be executed right away or still wait for the current job to finish?

If the 2nd one will have to wait until the first one is done, a related question is whether map tasks of the 2nd job can be run when the first job is done with its map tasks.

Answer (score 1):

First, each node in the cluster has fixed amount of slots, which are equally allocated to map tasks and reduce tasks. In a FIFO scheduler, it is not very efficient when skew occurs. For example, if the previous job has a map task or reduce task that takes "forever" to finish, then the whole system might halt. Fortunately, this is not gonna happen, because of speculative execution adopted in MapReduce. Once stragglers are detected, their clones will be started at other nodes.

Your first question: I think the answer is yes. The remaining capacity will be used by the next job of course.

Second question: when no remaining capacity is available, the next job has to wait. When the previous job finishes its map tasks, it means that slots for map task are freed. So the next job can start its map phase.